# Can I replace the white (default) background of one image with another?

Tags: .net, css

I have an image with a white background.  I also have a image being used as my background color (blue) on a repeat in my style sheet.  Is there a way to replace the white space with the blue background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant do this in css. You would need to edit your image to have a transparent background.